# Correct way to test if a rails page is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, capybara

As my first baby-step into automated testing, I want to make sure all of the "GET"-type pages can be reached in the browser. My specifications also require:

- Works with Devise log-ins (devise only provides testing for RSpec, so do I need RSpec?)
- Has to check that the view can render. e.g, if I have <%= true = false %> in one of my views, and it bugs out when viewed in the browser, the automated test should pick this up. (It seems that RSpec doesn't support testing what is rendered in the view, so do I need capybara?)

My attempts today have required me to include RSpec, FactoryGirl, and Capybara (for checking the view). It's been a nightmare. Capybara is still not functioning.

Is this how most rails developers test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though most of the Devise examples use RSpec you can use Minitest (the built in Ruby test framework). Which you use is completely up to you but I feel that writing stupid Java-eske test classes in a language as dynamic as Ruby is just wrong.

This is just opinion though.

Getting a decent test suite setup the first time can be a pain but does pay off the long run.

Usually I test at three levels:

### Model specs

which test low level functions on your models. It's much  quicker & easier than trying to set up web requests to test how your models will react to different input.

Example of testing a Model with `rspec-its` and `rspec-mongoid`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Photo, type: :model do

  it { should validate_presence_of :flickr_uid }
  it { should belong_to_related :photoset }
  it { should belong_to :user }

  describe ".find_or_create_from_flickr" do
    subject do
      Photo.find_or_create_from_flickr(OpenStruct.new(
          id: 'ABC_123',
          title: 'foo'
      ))
    end

    its(:flickr_uid) { should eq 'ABC_123' }
    its(:title) { should eq 'foo' }
  end  
end
```

### [Feature specs](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara)

where you mimic the behavior of a visitor - clicking around and writing expectations on the page content. I write them with RSpec & Capybara. I try to at least cover the "happy" paths through the application.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "User profile management" do

  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  background do
    login_as user
  end

  def visit_profile_page
    visit root_path
    click_link user.nickname
  end

  scenario "a user can edit his profile" do
    visit_profile_page
    click_link I18n.t('users.show.edit_profile')
    page.fill_in I18n.t('simple_form.labels.user.name'), with: 'New Name'
    click_button 'Update User'
    expect(page).to have_content 'New Name'
  end

  scenario "a user can view index" do
    visit users_path
    expect(page).to have_link user.nickname
  end
end
```

### Controller specs

tests the API of the application. I usually just test a that the controller:

- returns the correct HTTP code.
- renders the correct template.
- authorizes the user and denies access if not authorized.

Example of controller spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/controller_spec_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do

  include ControllerSpecHelper

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  before { set_current_user(nil) }
  subject { response }

  describe "GET #show" do
    before { get :show, id: user }
    it { should have_http_status :success }
    it { should render_template :show }

    it "should assign user as @user" do
      expect(assigns(:user)).to be_a User
    end
  end

  describe "GET #edit" do
    context "when unauthorized" do
      it "denies access" do
        expect {
          get :edit, id: user
        }.to raise_error(CanCan::AccessDenied)
      end
    end

    context "when authorized" do
      before do
        set_current_user(user)
        get :edit, id: user
      end
      it { should have_http_status :success }
      it { should render_template :edit }

      it "should assign user as @user" do
        expect(assigns(:user)).to be_a User
      end
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Whats missing is view specs (usually not needed since you should not have too much logic in your views anyways and feature specs should cover the essentials) and routing specs which I seldom use.

Comment: This is brilliant. Just set up the first integration tests and controller tests. Thank you!